# How can one clear all the variables but the ones wanted

Tags: matlab

Often when running long memory expensive programs I want to clear everything but some specific variables. If one wants to delete just some variables `clear varA varB` can be used, but what about deleting all but this specific variables?

Comment: While `clear` does allow for a regex pattern matching, [`clearvars`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) is probably more relevant, particularly the third syntax.

Comment: @excaza Wow didnt know about that one! post an answer!

Comment: Instead clear your vars whenever you are finished with them. It is a must in Matlab as it doesn't understand functional chains with multiple arguments.

Comment: @percusse yeah but sometimes I do a level set with 50 cosntarins in aloop, and I want to delete all but the result, as lots of them are mid variables.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I hear you loud and clear. Those stuff I tend to push inside a cell and delete the cell afterwards. Mid vars are really super annoying.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned above, [`clearvars`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) includes a syntax for keeping variables in the workspace while clearing the remainder:

```
a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1;
keepvars = {'c', 'd'};

clearvars('-except', keepvars{:});
```

Which functions as expected.

Like [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html), it can also accommodate [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) matching:

```
a1 = 1; a2 = 1; b = 1; c = 1;
keepvars = 'a\d'; % regex pattern

clearvars('-except', '-regexp', keepvars);
```

Which retains `a1` and `a2`, as expected.

Answer (score 10):

Make use of the fact that both `who` and `whos` have return values that can be stored in variables. The former returns a cell array of strings, the latter a struct array. For what you need, the former will suffice:

```
%// don't delete these '
keepvars = {'varA','varB'};

%// delete these
delvars = setdiff(who,keepvars);
clear(delvars{:},'delvars');
```