# How to display only specific variables in Matlab workspace

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have 100 variables in Matlab workspace. For example I take 5 variables here:

```
Matrix
Sum
Addition
Area
Perimeter
Subtraction
```

...and so forth.

How can I select or filter out a variable name based on some keyword like`Add` or a search term which selects the variable `Addition` in the workspace. I used the `who` command as

```
who -regexp Add
```

But this only displays the name of the variable and not its value.

Answer (score 2):

One of the rare occasions where [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) is possibly the most appropriate approach. (*gasp*)

You can use the functional version (see: [Syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html)) of [`who`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html) to store the names of the variables that match the [regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) in a cell array. If you iterate over these names with `eval` it will behave as if they were being called from the command line, which will display their values if not suppressed.

For example:

```
Matrix = rand(3);
Sum = rand(3);
Addition = rand(3);
Area = rand(3);
Perimeter = rand(3);
Subtraction = rand(3);
Additional = rand(3);

vars = who('-regexp', '[Aa]dd');
for ii = 1:numel(vars)
    eval(vars{ii})
end
```

Displays:

```
Addition =

    0.8143    0.3500    0.6160
    0.2435    0.1966    0.4733
    0.9293    0.2511    0.3517


Additional =

    0.6892    0.0838    0.1524
    0.7482    0.2290    0.8258
    0.4505    0.9133    0.5383
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have another question. This displays the values of the variables in the command window. How to get only these variables in the workspace as well, so that it can be clicked and viewed.

Comment: They are already in the workspace where they can be clicked and viewed... You could use `FilteredVars.(vars{ii})=eval(vars{ii})` to store them in a struct which, when explored in the workspace would only contain your variables. However, note you would be duplicating all those variables in memory, and they would not be linked to the actual values in the workspace.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676687/how-can-one-clear-all-the-variables-but-the-ones-wanted/34676847#34676847) for clearing variables except for those matching a regex.